# How to efficiently perform multiple MongoDB queries, removing search parameters each time?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I want to perform a query with parameters `paramA` and `paramB`. If I get zero results, I then want to query my database only with `paramB` and see how many results I get with just the one parameter.

So far I can think of making two separate queries, or querying just for `paramB` in one query and manually removing results that don't also match `paramA`. Both seem inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo DB supports $OR and $AND operator, and this problem can be easily solved using these.

```
{
  "$OR": [
    {
      "$AND": [
        {
          "paramA": "abc"
        },
        {
          "paramB": "def"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "paramB": "def"
    }
  ]
}
```

Request you to kindly try this once.
and use these for reference
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: I also need to know by which OR clause the results are returned. Basically I want to perform a very specific search. Only if that search returns no results, then I need to perform a more generalized search to see how many items are in my database at all. If that second search returns 0 results, then I need to perform an external operation.